JSON data from network fetch contains attribute values which should be undefined
I am using ParseServer to provide JSON data for my web client. The JSON contains a nested hierarchy of attributes containing arrays of Parse Objects. The Firefox network inspector proves that the JSON provided by my server is accurate. So far so good.
let tableContent = await Parse.Cloud.run("FetchTableContent", fetchParams)
However when I perform this fetch in my web client, then delete an attribute (call it 'foo') from one of the objects in my database, (value for object.foo is now 'undefined') and I call this network fetch again, the attribute value I removed is still contained in the resulting JSON.
The old cached value is only cleared when I refresh the web page with the browser's refresh button.
And remember, the network inspector shows that each time I run the fetch it provides the correct data.
All this evidence suggests the only way for this to be happening is that the JS SDK for Parse has a cache invalidation problem when an object loses an attribute. And I didn't expect any caching to begin with here. I wonder if anyone has an idea about working around this.
I tried adding a random number to the request params in case that could force it to invalidate but no luck.

Perhaps the only solution will be to run the POST manually outside of the SDK's Parse.Cloud.run method. Ugh what a headache.
